# Как прописать координаты для groupbox?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qgroupbox

`groupBox` появляется с размерами, которые я прописал. 
Я поместил его в `QVBoxLayout`, но мне нужно прописать ему точные координаты 
в **`x = 170`**, **`y = 200`**.

Пробовал с `setGeometry(QRect())`, но если его прописываю без `QVBoxLayout` я не понимаю как его отобразить. Как это сделать?

[image]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и покажите на изображении что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример,
который демонстрирует проблему.

Вам не надо помещать `groupBox` в `layout`.

Сделайте `groupBox` дочерним виджету, на котором вы его хотите разместить

```
groupBox = QGroupBox(self)
```

и переместите его куда вам надо.

```
groupBox.move(170, 200)
```

А теперь попробуйте изменять размеры окна.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('<h1>Hello World.</h1>', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter))

        groupBox = QGroupBox(self)                       # +++ self
        groupBox.setFixedSize(411, 251)
        groupBox.move(170, 200)                          # +++ x = 170, y = 200
        groupBox.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #D83A56; "
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "background-color: #ccffbd77;"
        )
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.resize(760, 650)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо